# Smooch: How can I get the input from the user after he has entered something?

Tags: input, response, bots, smooch

My bot is working again! BUT 
I have a script asking the user for his name.
So I went through all topics on stack and the repos in github but somehow it never clicked.

My question is How can I get the input from the user after he has entered something - based on the scripts request?
(Would it involve postback or do I need to let smooch listen for messages or or or?

Thanks for any help!

Wouter

Answer (score 0):

Using the [smooch-bot](https://github.com/smooch/smooch-bot) library, in the `receive` callback of your script file, the second parameter is the user's message. You can use that message object to know what the user has said. You can see this in action in the [smooch-bot-example](https://github.com/smooch/smooch-bot-example/blob/master/script.js#L18-L27) repo:

```
askName: {
    prompt: (bot) => bot.say('What\'s your name?'),
    receive: (bot, message) => {
        const name = message.text;
        return bot.setProp('name', name)
            .then(() => bot.say(`Great! I'll call you ${name} Is that OK? %[Yes](postback:yes) %[No](postback:no)`))
            .then(() => 'finish');
    }
}
```

You can use `message.text`, as in the example above, to get the reply to your question

Comment: hey @michaels

thanks for that - I saw that too > but what I am looking for is, so to speak, a user based prompt with the bot responding through the script.

Comment: you mean to say that you need the user's message in the `prompt` callback, instead of the `receive` callback?

Comment: You can set a user prop like this: https://github.com/smooch/smooch-bot-example/blob/master/script.js#L22 and then echo back that user prop like this: https://github.com/smooch/smooch-bot-example/blob/master/script.js#L32

Comment: i can find a lot of stuff but not where or how i need to deal with my callback from a button like

%[text](postback:yes)  followed/watched by

yes {
 prompt (bot) => bot.say('For sure')
}

I am either too dumb or reading in the wrong places. So some help would be most appreaciated

cheers

wouter

Comment: update: I guess at the time of writing I was still too dumb...so following all the projects of https://github.com/alavers > smooch docs for example helped me  :)

topic closed.